# jquery cycle2 initialisation with complex types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle

Hello I'm making the transition from the old cycle to cylcle2 and I'm trying to get my old code to work but cant seam to find what's wrong. So I use the declarative way to initialize my cycle, the code is

```
<script>
    $('#container').cycle({
        fx: "scrollHorz",
        timeout: 2000,
        speed: 700
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
<div class="act">
<a href="link">
<h3>Title</h3></a>
<div id="action_text"> 
<a href="link2">
<div class="clip_action"><img src="/thumb_cycle/img.jpg"></div></a>
<p>Description text.</p></div>
</div>

<div class="act">
<a href="link">
<h3>Title2</h3></a>
<div id="action_text"> 
<a href="link3">
<div class="clip_action"><img src="/thumb_cycle/img.jpg"></div></a>
<p>Description text.</p></div>
</div>
...
```

So the problem is that I don't have a simple structure to scroll over like only images, I have a div with lots of info. I managed to get it working with the inline div by calling  data-cycle-slides=".act", so i tried the same thing with the declarative style ie:

```
<script>
    $('#container').cycle({
        fx: "scrollHorz",
        timeout: 2000,
        speed: 700,
        slides: ".act"
    });
</script>
```

But it does not work, any ideas on where the problem might be?